# Read promise value and pass it to next method of an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

On Angular 9 I created the following interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return from(this.authenticationService.getAuthenticationHeader()).pipe(header => {

      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: { 
          Authorization: `${header}`
        }
      });

      return next.handle(request);

    });

  }

}
```

The method `authenticationService.getAuthenticationHeader()` returns a `Promise<string>` where the string is the header value which I need to add to the request.

So I use `from` to convert the Promise to an `Observable` and `pipe` on the `Observable`.

Do I need to use `map` after `pipe`?

And is this the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're returning an observable, the appropriate operator would be the [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap).

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return from(this.authenticationService.getAuthenticationHeader()).pipe(
      switchMap(header => {         // <-- use `switchMap` here
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: { 
            Authorization: `${header}`
          }
        });
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Would mergeMap also be an option? Or swicthMap is enough because of the value coming from a Promise?

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference here since the promise will emit only one event. You could as well use `concatMap`. But `switchMap` would be more semantically appropriate.